# Ubuntu AWS SSH authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

I need to understand something here.

In AWS console, the key pair's name of an instance is "abc" and the if I SSH to the instance, it will use the default user "ubuntu".

When I check the `authorized_keys` file of the user "ubuntu", it has the following format:

`ssh-rsa <some_long_string_nonsense> abc`

As you can see, it uses the key pair's name in AWS console only **and** without the host.

On the other hand, when I created a new user "usertest" in the same instance and assign a key pair of it's own using `ssh-copy-id` from my local machine. The format, again is not what I expected:

`ssh-rsa <some_long_string_nonsense> root@ip-172-12-32-443`

This time it uses "root" along with the instance's private IP address.

Based on [Ubuntu's SSH/OpenSSH/Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys), shouldn't the format be as the following?

1. `ssh-rsa <some_long_string_nonsense> ubuntu@public_ip_address`
2. `ssh-rsa <some_long_string_nonsense> usertest@public_ip_address`

Answer (score 0):

The final argument, `abc` or `root@ip-172-12-32-443`, is just a comment and can be anything you please.  It puts it in there automatically just so you can identify what that particular line is for.  If you wanted, you can swap it out for `default AWS-installed key for user abc` or even `work login`.  Both of the formats you've seen are the same format.